# Fetch Data From Swift NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutable array i am populating it with some data, but when i try to Log it using

```
NSLog("\(mutableArrayName)");
```

it gives me results in the following form

```
{
    0x05708e80 = 0x05708f00;
    0x05709a80 = 0x05709a00;
    0x05709b80 = 0x05708f80;
},
    {
    0x05708e80 = 0x05708f00;
    0x05709a80 = 0x05709a00;
    0x05709b80 = 0x05708f80;
}
```

How can i fetch my data from this result.

Comment: Can you please put some code?

Comment: @NakulSharma its var mutableArrayName = NSMutableArray();

Comment: Have you checked in-memory queue ? What is the value of `mutableArrayName` at runtime ?

Comment: What type of items are you adding to the array? How you fetch data from the array depends on the type of objects you are putting in the array.

Comment: you might be missing some thing like **textFieled** for only **textField.text** while adding data to dictionary .